# How to use Enum with schema in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a table inside a schema using SQLAlchemy. It has a column of type Enum. Following is the code

```py
import enum
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import Column, Text, Enum
from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateSchema
import sqlalchemy_utils
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class T(enum.Enum):
    X = 1
    Y = 2

ET = Enum(T, inherit_schema=True)
#ET = Enum(T, schema="schema1") # This works

class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'a'

    c1 = Column(Text, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    c2 = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    c3 = Column(ET)

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("postgresql://postgres:mypass@172.17.0.2/mydb")

engine.execute(CreateSchema('schema1'))

schema_engine = engine.execution_options(schema_translate_map = { None: "schema1" } )
Base.metadata.create_all(schema_engine)
```

This fails at the "create_all" line with the following error

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.DuplicateObject)
> type "t" already exists  [SQL: "CREATE TYPE schema1.t AS ENUM ('X',
> 'Y')"] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)

I am using this pattern because I will have multiple schemas inside which the same table has to be created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you get the error is because there is a [bug](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5520) in the version that you are using.

I would suggest to use a virtual environment and use the latest stable release of SQLAlchemy.

Comment: Can you provide some instructions on how to upgrade to the latest version of `SQLAlchemy`? (Either link to reference, or actual instructions) Would make your answer a lot helpful.